# Unable to make instance on Google Cloud Platform with startup-script-url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, gsutil, gpc

I can't create instance in GCP with gcloud console:

**1. If script local, everything it OK:**

```
gcloud compute instances create app \
--boot-disk-size=10GB \
--image-family ubuntu-1604-lts \
--image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud \
--machine-type=g1-small \
--restart-on-failure \
--metadata-from-file startup-script=install.sh
```

**2. If I user startup-script-url with gsutil URI, like this:**

```
gcloud compute instances create app \
--boot-disk-size=10GB \
--image-family ubuntu-1604-ltsm \
--image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud \
--machine-type=g1-small \
--restart-on-failure \
--metadata-from-file startup-script-url=gs://mbps54/install.sh
```

Then I received:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Unable to read file
> [gs://mbps54/install.sh]. [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'gs://mbps54/install.sh' gsutil URI is gs://mbps54/install.sh

**3. If I user startup-script-url with Public URL,like this:**

```
gcloud compute instances create reddit-app \
--boot-disk-size=10GB \
--image-family ubuntu-1604-ltsm \
--image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud \
--machine-type=g1-small \
--restart-on-failure \
--metadata-from-file startup-script-url=https://storage.googleapis.com/mbps54/install.sh
```

I received:**

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Unable to read file
> [https://storage.googleapis.com/mbps54/install.sh]: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mbps54/install.sh'

**4. Here are my bucket settings**
[image: GPC Bucket settings]

And I can open https://storage.googleapis.com/mbps54/install.sh from any other PC.
Additionally, to make sure access is public, I did this:

```
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://mbps54
gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://mbps54
```

**5. This bucket url is Public and opens from any PC**
https://storage.googleapis.com/mbps54/install.sh opens from other PC.

Could somebody help, what is wrong with my configuration and script?

Answer (score 4):

You're using the `--metadata-from-file` flag, which expects you to supply a local file.  If you want to specify a startup script from a URL instead, you want the `--metadata` flag, i.e.:

```
--metadata startup-script-url=URL
```

This is mentioned at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances under the `gcloud` tab.

> Using the gcloud command-line tool, use the instances add-metadata command to add metadata to the instance. Use any of the available startup script keys:
>
> `--metadata startup-script=CONTENTS`: supply the startup script
> contents directly by using this key.
>
> `--metadata startup-script-url=URL`: supply a Cloud Storage URL to the startup
> script file by using this key. `--metadata-from-file
>
> `startup-script=FILE`: supply a locally stored startup script file.
>
> For example:
>
> ````
> --metadata-from-file startup-script=PATH_TO_FILE
>
> gcloud compute instances add-metadata EXAMPLE_INSTANCE \   --metadata
> startup-script-url=gs://BUCKET/FILE ```
> ````

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! "--metadata startup-script-url=gs://mbps54/install.sh" - that is the correct syntax.